# Simple Calculator - If statement

Tags: java

I am new to java and programming.
Can someone suggest what can be used so that the answer must equal to `+,-,*,/ ?` At the moment I am trying to create an if statement but I am getting an error and I am not quite sure why. Can someone look at my code and help me complete the if statement please? If you have any other suggestions on what can be improved, please share.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
public static void main (String Args []) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double firstNumber, secondNumber;
    String equationOperator;

    System.out.println("Please give your first number: \t");
    firstNumber = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please give your second number: \t");
    secondNumber = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Which equation would you like to perform?");
    System.out.println("Please enter one of the following + - / * \t");
    equationOperator = input.next();

    switch (equationOperator) {
    case "+":
        System.out.println("Your chosen equation is: Adding");
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (firstNumber + secondNumber));
        break;
    case "-":
        System.out.println("Your chosen equation is: Subtracting");
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (firstNumber - secondNumber));
        break;
    case "/":
        System.out.println("Your chosen equation is: Dividing");
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (firstNumber / secondNumber));
        break;
    case "*":
        System.out.println("You chosen equation is: Multiplying");
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (firstNumber * secondNumber));
        break;                  
    }
    if (!equationOperator.equals("+ || - || / || *") {
        System.out.println("Please choose one of the following:");
        System.out.println("+"
                + "-"
                + "/"
                + "*");
                }
    System.out.println("\t Thank You for using my Calculator");

        }


 }
```

Comment: try System.out.println(equationOperator); to debug

Comment: "+ || - || / || *"` is just a string with those letters in it. It don't magically assume this is code.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in your condition:

```
if (!equationOperator.equals("+ || - || / || *") {
```

should be

```
if (!equationOperator.equals("+ || - || / || *")) {
```

Note that this won't give you the expected result either, as you are checking for the *exact* string "`+ || - || / || *`".

You would either need several `equals`, e.g.

```
if (!equationOperator.equals("+") && !equationOperator.equals("-") ...) {
```

or simply use the `default` case in your `switch` statement:

```
switch (equationOperator) {
    case "+":
        System.out.println("Your chosen equation is: Adding");
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (firstNumber + secondNumber));
        break;
    case "-":
        System.out.println("Your chosen equation is: Subtracting");
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (firstNumber - secondNumber));
        break;
    case "/":
        System.out.println("Your chosen equation is: Dividing");
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (firstNumber / secondNumber));
        break;
    case "*":
        System.out.println("You chosen equation is: Multiplying");
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (firstNumber * secondNumber));
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Please choose one of the following:");
        System.out.println("+"
            + "-"
            + "/"
            + "*");         
}
```

The `default` case will be executed when none of the other matches. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use a default case in switch

```
default:
                System.out.println("Please choose one of the following:");
        System.out.println("+"
                + "-"
                + "/"
                + "*");
                }
```

Also your if statement is incorrect apart from ) bracket missing from end.

if (!equationOperator.equals("+ || - || / || *")) This compares your equationOperator with string "+ || - || / || *" .

You wanted this

> if (!(equationOperator.equals("+") || equationOperator.equals("-") ||
>   equationOperator.equals("/") || equationOperator.equals("*"))) {